# Convert stars-and-bars combination to number N and back

Tags: combinatorics, number-systems

I was wondering if there is a way to convert from any of the $$\binom{n + k - 1}{n}$$ combinations in a stars and bars setting to a unique number N with $$0 <= N < \binom{n+k-1}{n}$$ and viceversa from a number N to the same combination back.

I am assuming that bins are different, and the information about them must be preserved. I have found [the wikipedia article on combinadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) but it assumes that the combinations are sorted by size, which would lose the ordering information of the bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [stars and bars article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), you are selecting $n$ places to put dividers out of $n+k-1$ so we can let $m=n+k-1$ and find a way to make a correspondence between a particular serial number and a particular selection.  Of the $m \choose n$ combinations, ${m-1 \choose n-1}$ include $1$ and ${m-1 \choose n}$ do not.  If we list the combinations in lexicographic order, the former will come before the latter, so if $N \lt {m-1 \choose n-1}$ we will include $1$ and if $N \ge {m-1 \choose n-1}$ we will not.  In the first case we are looking for the $N^{th}$ combination of $n-1$ items out of $2,3,4,\ldots m$.  In the second we are looking for the $N-{m-1 \choose n-1}^{th}$ combination of $n$ items out of $2,3,4,\ldots m$.  This gives a nice recursive algorithm as one of the values has been reduced.

Comment: I think I've got how to convert a combination to N, I'm counting the number of combinations before my own for each specific element and recursing. I'll now try to understand how exactly to do the opposite.