# Compositions of a large integer

Tags: probability, combinatorics, uniform-distribution

Let's say $n$ is the number of integers and $t$ is their sum and we want to find all the combinations of number $t$, such that there are $n$ components. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

This is implemented in R under [Partition library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/).

```
library(partitions)

# In this example, we impose condition 
# that each rows must sum up to 2 in total
# And each row has 5 columns
t <- 2
n <- 5
#The above two parameters are predefined.

t(as.matrix(compositions(t, n)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    2    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    2    0    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    2    0    0
 [7,]    1    0    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    2    0
[11,]    1    0    0    0    1
[12,]    0    1    0    0    1
[13,]    0    0    1    0    1
[14,]    0    0    0    1    1
[15,]    0    0    0    0    2
```

How ever, if $n,t>1000$ it becomes too slow to save all the compositions. I would like to only get $m$ compositions, such that they are picked randomly from all possible compositions. We assume that all compositions have the same probability of being picked i.e. they are uniformly distributed.

Comment: I describe a recursive algorithm to pick a random combination [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729306/convert-stars-and-bars-combination-to-number-n-and-back/2729368#2729368)  You can choose a random number from $1$ to the number of compositions, then use this to pick a combination and use the bijection between combinations and compositions.

Comment: What if a composition has more than $1$ of some number, for example a composition $(1,1,0,0,0)$? How would your method detect that? Also, do you have a reference or a proof that it works?

Comment: In stars and bars for weak compositions you add $1$ to all the numbers, so $(1,1,0,0,0)$ corresponds to the strong composition $(2,2,1,1,1)$ of $7$ into $5$ pieces.  The positions of the dividers are a four element subset of $6$, which here is $\{2,4,5,6\}$.  My approach would find that subset.  Whether there are duplicates does not matter, but is not detected.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the recursive algorithm works for my example, which deals with weak $n$-compositions of $t$. I understand that we generate an index (from 1 to total number of compositions) and then use the recursive algorithm to determine the number of $0$-s, $1$-s,...,$t$-s.

Comment: Do you see how to go to combinations of $n-1$ items out of $t+n-1$?  This is detailed on the stars and bars page.  Then you compute the number of combinations that include $1$.  If your combination number is less than that, include $1$.  If not, exclude $1$ and reduce the combination number by the number that include $1$.  Now look for combinations of $n-2$ items out of $t+n-2$ with that combination number.  We have gone one step down the recursion because there are fewer items to choose from.

Comment: If knowing the lexicographic index of the composition is not important, wouldn't it be simpler to draw $n$ numbers uniformly from $\{0,1,2,\ldots ,t\}$. These represent the bars. To get the composition, we count the number of stars between the bars and construct a vector (number of stars until the first bar, number of stars until the second bar, ... ,number of stars until the last bar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97695/discussion-between-scippy-and-ross-millikan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (many different) ways to enumerate the compositions (you can, for example, use the correspondence given with binary representations of numbers described in the Wikipedia link you give), so you can write a function translating between the index of a composition and the composition itself. Then you can simply select $m$ numbers at random (from an appropriate range) and retrieve the corresponding compositions.