Lexicographical List of (n,k)-Combinations [k-subsets], without Repetition: calculate the N-th List-entry
Consider a $k$-selection from an $n$-set $S=\{0,1,\dots, n-1 \}$, without order, without repetition; 
that means a $(n,k)$-combination, without repetition. 
Imagine all possible selections listed.
Then there are different ways to specify this list; e.g.

list entries in the combinatorial number system; 
if $n=5,~ k=3,~ S=\{0,1,2,\dots, n-1 \}:$ 2 1 0, 3 1 0, 3 2 0,...
List entries in lexicographical order;
if $n=5,~ k=3,~ S=\{1,2,\dots,n \}:$ 1 2 3, 1 2 4, 1 2 5,...

At Combinatorial number system or at this calculator page an algorithm is described that allows any list position to be determined for listing the entry in the combinatorial number system: 

Let $N$ be the number of the list entry that is being searched (e.g. $N=7$).
Find maximum $c_k$ which holds ${\tbinom {c_{k}}{k}}\leq N$
Find maximum $c_{k-1}$ which holds ${\tbinom {c_{k-1}}{k-1}}\leq N - {\tbinom {c_{k}}{k}}$
...
Find maximum $c_1$ which holds ${\tbinom {c_1}{1}}\leq N - {\tbinom {c_{k}}{k}} - {\tbinom {c_{k-1}}{k-1}} - \cdots - {\tbinom {c_2}{2}}$
$c_k, c_{k-1},\dots, c_1$ is the searched list entry.

For $n=5,~ k=3,~ \binom{5}{3}=10$ this results in the columns $\text{CNS1},~ \text{CNS2},~ \text{CNS3}$ in the following table. 
In contrast, let $\text{Lex1},~ \text{Lex2},~ \text{Lex3}$ be the list entries of the lexicographical order.
$\begin{array}{c c c c | c c c c}
\hline
\text{No. CNS} & \text{CNS1} & \text{CNS2}  &  \text{CNS3}  
  &  \text{No. Lex}  &  \text{Lex1}  
   &  \text{Lex2}  &  \text{Lex3} \\ \hline
0  &  2  &  1  &  0  &  1  &  1  &  2  &  3 \\
1  &  3  &  1  &  0  &  2  &  1  &  2  &  4 \\
2  &  3  &  2  &  0  &  3  &  1  &  2  &  5 \\
3  &  3  &  2  &  1  &  4  &  1  &  3  &  4 \\
4  &  4  &  1  &  0  &  5  &  1  &  3  &  5 \\
5  &  4  &  2  &  0  &  6  &  1  &  4  &  5 \\
6  &  4  &  2  &  1  &  7  &  2  &  3  &  4 \\
7  &  4  &  3  &  0  &  8  &  2  &  3  &  5 \\
8  &  4  &  3  &  1  &  9  &  2  &  4  &  5 \\
9  &  4  &  3  &  2  &  10  &  3  &  4  &  5 \\ \hline
\end{array}$
Question:
Is there an algorithm that allows to directly calculate the $N$th list entry of the lexocographic list? Or is it possible to adjust the shown algorithm here?

Yes.  I sketched it at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729306/convert-stars-and-bars-combination-to-number-n-and-back/2729368#2729368.  It is easier for lexicographic.  You go through the entries.  Find how many start with $1$, divide $N$ by this and round up.  You have the first element.  Now subtract off the entries that have a smaller first element and find the second.  Recurse.

@RossMillikan Interesting.  My answer seems to have followed the same logical path, but with different syntax.

Per OP's (i.e. original poster's) comment-request, added an Addendum to provide illustrative examples of the algorithm.

$\underline{\text{Overview}}$
Assume that $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n\},~$ and that $~p \in \Bbb{Z} ~: ~1 \leq p \leq \displaystyle \binom{n}{k}.~$
Let an entry denote the selection of $~k~$ elements from $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$
where the elements are selected in ascending order.
Assume that the complete list of the $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}~$ entries are to be listed in lexicographical order.
Let $~d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_k~$ represent a specific entry, where $~d_1 < d_2 < \cdots < d_k.$
Then, you are looking for a formula for the $~p$-th entry.
That is, you are looking for a formula that expresses each of $~d_1, ~d_2, ~\cdots, ~d_k~$ as a function of $~p.~$
A recursive formula will be supplied.
For ease of syntax, throughout this answer, I will adopt the conventions that when $~x < y,~$ that

$\displaystyle \binom{x}{y} = 0.$ 
$\displaystyle \sum_y^x ~[ ~\text{any expression} ~] = 0.$

Throughout this answer, the hockey stick identity will be used. That is
$$\sum_{i = m}^n \binom{i}{m} = \binom{n+1}{m+1}. \tag1 $$
As a direct consequence of this identity, for $~a,b \in \Bbb{Z} ~: ~1 \leq a \leq b \leq n-m,~$ you have that
$$\sum_{i = a}^b \binom{n-i}{m} = \sum_{i = n-b}^{n-a} \binom{i}{m}
= \left[ ~\sum_{i = m}^{n-a} \binom{i}{m} ~\right] - \left[ ~\sum_{i = m}^{n-b-1} \binom{i}{m} ~\right]$$
$$= \binom{n+1-a}{m+1} - \binom{n-b}{m+1}. \tag2 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~d_1}$
The first $~\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k-1}~$ entries will have $~d_1 = 1.~$
Then, the next $~\displaystyle \binom{n-2}{k-1}~$ entries, will have $~d_1 = 2.~$
Then, the next $~\displaystyle \binom{n-3}{k-1}~$ entries, will have $~d_1 = 3.~$
$~\cdots~$
The last entry will have $~d_1 = (n+1-k).$
So, you can define $~d_1~$ as the smallest positive integer such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{d_1} \binom{n-i}{k-1} \geq p.$$
Using (2) above, $~d_1~$ is the smallest positive integer such that
$$\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n - d_1}{k} \geq p \iff \binom{n}{k} - p \geq \binom{n - d_1}{k}. \tag3 $$

$\underline{\text{Recursive computation of} ~d_{r+1} ~: ~1 \leq r \leq k - 1}$
This section will make repeated use of the identity in (2) above.
To complete the specification of $~d_1, ~d_2, ~\cdots, ~d_k~$ as a function of $~p,~$ a recursive formula is needed that expresses $~d_{r+1}~$ as a function of both $~p~$ and the components $~d_1, ~d_2, ~\cdots, ~d_r,~$ where $~r \in \{1,2,\cdots,k-1\}.$
Let $~p_1~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{d_1 - 1} \binom{n-i}{k-1} = \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n+1-d_1}{k}.~$
So, $~p_1~$ represents the number of entries where the first component of the entry was strictly less than $~d_1.~$
Let $~p_2~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=d_1 + 1}^{d_2 - 1} \binom{n-i}{k-2} = \binom{n - d_1}{k-1} - \binom{n + 1 - d_2}{k-1}.~$
So, $~p_2~$ represents the number of entries where the first component of the entry was specifically $~d_1,~$ and the second component of the entry was strictly less than $~d_2.~$
Therefore, the sum $~( ~p_1 + p_2 ~)~$ equals the number of entries that were lexicographically less than $~d_1, d_2.$
Continuing in this manner, for $~s \in \{ ~3, ~4, ~\cdots, ~r ~\},~$ 
let $~p_s~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=d_{(s-1)} + 1}^{d_s - 1} \binom{n-i}{k-s} = \binom{n - d_{(s-1)}}{k +1 - s} - \binom{n+1-d_s}{k +1 - s}.~$
Then the sum $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^r p_i~$ equals the number of entries that were lexicographically less than $~d_1, d_2, d_3, \cdots, d_r.$
Further,
$$\sum_{i=1}^r p_i = \left[ ~\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n+1 - d_1}{k} ~\right]$$
$$+ \left\{ ~\sum_{s=2}^r \left[ ~\binom{n - d_{(s-1)}}{k+1-s} - \binom{n+1 - d_s}{k +1 - s} ~\right]  ~\right\}. \tag4 $$
$$\text{Let} ~q = p - [ ~p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_r ~]. \tag5 $$
At this point, with $~d_r~$ and $~q~$ specified, the computation of $~d_{r+1}~$ is  analytically parallel to the original computation of $~d_1.$
That is, you have to select $~(k-r)~$ elements from the set
$~\{ ~d_r + 1, ~d_r + 2, ~\cdots, ~n ~\}.$
So, you can define $~d_{r+1}~$ as the smallest positive integer such that
$$\binom{n - d_r}{k - r} - q \geq \binom{n - d_{(r+1)}}{k-r}. \tag6 $$

$\underline{\text{Final Summary}}$
Assume that $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k \in \{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots, ~n\},~$ and that $~p \in \Bbb{Z} ~: ~1 \leq p \leq \displaystyle \binom{n}{k}.~$
$d_1~$ is the smallest positive integer such that
$$\binom{n}{k} - p \geq \binom{n - d_1}{k}. $$
The remainder of this section assumes that the components $~d_1, ~d_2, ~\cdots, ~d_r~$ have been selected, where $~1 \leq r \leq k-1.$
$$\text{Let} ~q = p - \left[ ~\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n+1 - d_1}{k} ~\right]$$
$$- \left\{ ~\sum_{s=2}^r \left[ ~\binom{n - d_{(s-1)}}{k+1-s} - \binom{n+1 - d_s}{k +1 - s} ~\right]  ~\right\}.$$
Then $~d_{r+1}~$ is the smallest positive integer such that
$$\binom{n - d_r}{k - r} - q \geq \binom{n - d_{(r+1)}}{k-r}.$$

$\underline{\text{Sanity Check}}$
I wrote a small program to compute $~d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5~$ for $~n = 20, ~k = 5, ~p = 10000.$
The program lexicographically 5-nested-looped, incrementing a counter for each iteration of the 5th loop.  The result was
$~d_1 = 4, ~d_2 = 6, ~d_3 = 10, ~d_4 = 14, ~d_5 = 20.~$
Then, I used a calculator to manually logic-walk-through my recursive procedure.  The results matched.
For what it's worth, when you construct the computer program to implement the algorithm, there is a (small) opportunity to optimize the code.
Assume, (for example) that you have just computed $~p_1 + p_2 + p_3,~$ and then computed $~q = p - (p_1 + p_2 + p_3).~$
In the next pass through the algorithm, you do not need to re-calculate $~p_1, ~p_2, ~$ or $~p_3.$  That is, the value of these variables won't change, and so all that you have to do is

compute $~p_4.~$

then re-compute $~q = [ ~p - (p_1 + p_2 + p_3) ~] - p_4 = q - p_4,$ 
where the expression $~(q - p_4)~$ signifies using the value of $~q~$ from the previous iteration.





$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Per OP's request, I am adding illustrative examples.
In these examples, I will let $~q_r~$ denote the value of $~q~$ that is calculated after variable $~d_r~$ is already calculated, and just before variable $~d_{r+1}~$ is about to be calculated.  As discussed in the "Sanity Check" section of this answer, this facilitates using the following shortcut:
$$q_r = q_{r-1} - p_r = q_{r-1} - \left[ ~\binom{n - d_{(r-1)}}{k+1-r} - \binom{n+1 - d_r}{k +1 - r} ~\right].$$



Example: 1
$n = 20, k = 5, p = 10000.$
$$\displaystyle \binom{20}{5} - p = 15504 - 10000 = 5504.$$
$$6188 = \binom{20 - 3}{5} > 5504 \geq \binom{20-4}{5} = 4368 \implies $$
$$d_1 = 4. \tag{EX1.1}$$

$$q_1 = p -  \left[ ~\binom{20 }{5} - \binom{21 - d_1}{5} ~\right] $$
$$= 10000 - \left[ ~\binom{20 }{5} - \binom{21 - 4}{5} ~\right] = 684.$$
$$\binom{20 - d_1}{4} - q_1 = \binom{20 - 4}{4} - 684 = 1136.$$
$$ 1365 = \binom{20 - 5}{4} > 1136 \geq \binom{20 - 6}{4} = 1001 \implies $$
$$ d_2 = 6. \tag{EX1.2} $$

$$q_2 = q_1 -  \left[ ~\binom{20 - d_1 }{4} - \binom{21 - d_2}{4} ~\right] $$
$$= 684 - \left[ ~\binom{20 - 4}{4} - \binom{21 - 6}{4} ~\right] = 229.$$
$$\binom{20 - d_2}{3} - q_2 = \binom{20 - 6}{3} - 229 = 135.$$
$$ 165 = \binom{20 - 9}{3} > 135 \geq \binom{20 - 10}{3} = 120 \implies $$
$$ d_3 = 10. \tag{EX1.3} $$

$$q_3 = q_2 -  \left[ ~\binom{20 - d_2 }{3} - \binom{21 - d_3}{3} ~\right] $$
$$= 229 - \left[ ~\binom{20 - 6}{3} - \binom{21 - 10}{3} ~\right] = 30.$$
$$\binom{20 - d_3}{2} - q_3 = \binom{20 - 10}{2} - 30 = 15.$$
$$ 21 = \binom{20 - 13}{2} > 15 \geq \binom{20 - 14}{2} = 15 \implies $$
$$ d_4 = 14. \tag{EX1.4} $$

$$q_4 = q_3 -  \left[ ~\binom{20 - d_3 }{2} - \binom{21 - d_4}{2} ~\right] $$
$$= 30 - \left[ ~\binom{20 - 10}{2} - \binom{21 - 14}{2} ~\right] = 6.$$
$$\binom{20 - d_4}{1} - q_4 = \binom{20 - 14}{1} - 6 = 0.$$
$$ 1 = \binom{20 - 19}{1} > 0 \geq \binom{20 - 20}{1} = 0 \implies $$
$$ d_5 = 20. \tag{EX1.5} $$



Example: 2
$n = 5, k = 3, p = 7.$
$$\displaystyle \binom{5}{3} - p = 10 - 7 = 3.$$
$$4 = \binom{5 - 1}{3} > 3 \geq \binom{5 - 2}{3} = 1 \implies $$
$$d_1 = 2. \tag{EX2.1}$$

$$q_1 = p -  \left[ ~\binom{5}{3} - \binom{6 - d_1}{3} ~\right] $$
$$= 7 - \left[ ~\binom{5}{3} - \binom{4}{3} ~\right] = 1.$$
$$\binom{5 - d_1}{2} - q_1 = \binom{5 - 2}{2} - 1 = 2.$$
$$ 3 = \binom{5 - 2}{2} > 2 \geq \binom{5 - 3}{2} = 2 \implies $$
$$ d_2 = 3. \tag{EX2.2} $$

$$q_2 = q_1 -  \left[ ~\binom{5 - d_1 }{2} - \binom{6 - d_2}{2} ~\right] $$
$$= 1 - \left[ ~\binom{3 }{2} - \binom{3}{2} ~\right] = 1.$$
$$\binom{5 - d_2}{1} - q_2 = \binom{5 - 3}{1} - 1 = 1.$$
$$ 2 = \binom{5 - 3}{1} > 1 \geq \binom{5 - 4}{1} = 1 \implies $$
$$ d_3 = 4. \tag{EX2.3} $$



Example: 3
$n = 49, k = 6, p = 5000000.$
$$\displaystyle \binom{49}{6} - p = 13983816 - 5000000 = 8983816.$$
$$9366819 = \binom{49 - 3}{6} > 8983816 \geq \binom{49-4}{6} = 8145060 \implies $$
$$d_1 = 4. \tag{EX3.1}$$

$$q_1 = p -  \left[ ~\binom{49 }{6} - \binom{50 - d_1}{6} ~\right] $$
$$= 5000000 - \left[ ~\binom{49}{6} - \binom{46}{6} ~\right] = 383003.$$
$$\binom{49 - d_1}{5} - q_1 = \binom{49 - 4}{5} - 383003 = 838756.$$
$$ 850668 = \binom{49 - 7}{5} > 838756 \geq \binom{49 - 8}{5} = 749398 \implies $$
$$ d_2 = 8. \tag{EX3.2} $$

$$q_2 = q_1 -  \left[ ~\binom{49 - d_1 }{5} - \binom{50 - d_2}{5} ~\right] $$
$$= 383003 - \left[ ~\binom{49 - 4}{5} - \binom{50 - 8}{5} ~\right] = 11912.$$
$$\binom{49 - d_2}{4} - q_2 = \binom{49 - 8}{4} - 11912 = 89358.$$
$$ 91390 = \binom{49 - 9}{4} > 89358 \geq \binom{49 - 10}{4} = 82251 \implies $$
$$ d_3 = 10. \tag{EX3.3} $$

$$q_3 = q_2 -  \left[ ~\binom{49 - d_2 }{4} - \binom{50 - d_3}{4} ~\right] $$
$$= 11912 - \left[ ~\binom{49 - 8}{4} - \binom{50 - 10}{4} ~\right] = 2032.$$
$$\binom{49 - d_3}{3} - q_3 = \binom{49 - 10}{3} - 2032 = 7107.$$
$$ 7140 = \binom{49 - 13}{3} > 7107 \geq \binom{49 - 14}{3} = 6545 \implies $$
$$ d_4 = 14. \tag{EX3.4} $$

$$q_4 = q_3 -  \left[ ~\binom{49 - d_3 }{3} - \binom{50 - d_4}{3} ~\right] $$
$$= 2032 - \left[ ~\binom{49 - 10}{3} - \binom{50 - 14}{3} ~\right] = 33.$$
$$\binom{49 - d_4}{2} - q_4 = \binom{49 - 14}{2} - 33 = 562.$$
$$ 595 = \binom{49 - 14}{2} > 562 \geq \binom{49 - 15}{2} = 561 \implies $$
$$ d_5 = 15. \tag{EX3.5} $$

$$q_5 = q_4 -  \left[ ~\binom{49 - d_4}{2} - \binom{50 - d_5}{2} ~\right] $$
$$= 33 - \left[ ~\binom{49 - 14}{2} - \binom{50 - 15}{2} ~\right] = 33.$$
$$\binom{49 - d_5}{1} - q_5 = \binom{49 - 15}{1} - 33 = 1.$$
$$ 2 = \binom{49 - 47}{1} > 1 \geq \binom{49 - 48}{1} = 1 \implies $$
$$ d_6 = 48. \tag{EX3.6} $$

Wow. To make it clear: would it be presumptuous to ask whether you can demonstrate your algorithm using the numerical example $n=5,~k=3$?
Alternatively: could you calculate directly the $234$th lexicographic list entry in the lottery game "6 out of 49"?

@haver Requested examples placed in an Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.  I just noticed that in my Example-3, that has $~n = 49, ~k = 6,~$ I overlooked that you were asking for $~p = 234.$  Instead, I computed $~p = 5000000.$  I also sanity-checked my Example-3 results.

Note that the lexicographic list of subsets is obtained from the co-lexicographic list by reversing the list, and then inverting all of the subsets, where the inverse of a subset is obtained by replacing each element $x$ with $n-x$. This observation allows you to modify your formula for the co-lex ordering to obtain a formula for the lexicographic ordering.
I will use the notation $\text{lex}_{n,k}(i, j)$ to denote the $j^\text{th}$ smallest element ($1\le j\le k)$ of the $i^\text{th}$ subset $(1\le i\le \binom nk$) in the list of all subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with size $k$, sorted lexicographically. This is the entry of the $i^\text{th}$ row and $j^\text{th}$ column of the lex table in your post.
Then, let $\text{colex}_{n,k}(i, j)$ denote the $j^\text{th}$ smallest element $(1\le j\le k)$ of the $i^\text{th}$ subset $(0\le i\le \binom nk-1)$ in the list of all subsets of $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ with size $k$, sorted co-lexicographically. This is the entry of the $(i+1)^\text{st}$ row and $j^\text{th}$ column of the co-lex table in your post.
For any integer $i$ such that $1\le i\le \binom nk$, we have
$$
\text{lex}_{n,k}(i, j)=n - \text{colex}_{n,k}\left(\binom nk-i,k+1-j\right).
$$
Example
Let's say you wanted to compute the $123^\text{rd}$ subset in the list of size-$6$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,10\}$. The answer is a subset $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_6\}$, sorted increasing so $a_1<\dots<a_6$. In my notation, $a_j=\text{lex}_{10,6}(123,j)$.
Let us start by computing the smallest element, $a_1$. Using my formula,
$$
\begin{align}
a_1=\text{lex}_{10,6}(123,1)
&=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}\left(\binom{10}6-123,6+1-1\right)
\\
&=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(210-123,6)
\\
&=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87,6)
\end{align}
$$
That is, letting $\{c_1,\dots,c_6\}$ be the $87^\text{th}$ subset in the zero-indexed list of size-6 subsets of $\{0,\dots,9\}$, we want $10-c_6$. Using the combinatorial number system formula, $c_6$ is the greatest number such that $\binom{c_6}{6}\le 87$. You can check that $\binom{9}6\le 87$ and $\binom{10}6> 87$, so we get $c_6=9$, and therefore
$$
a_1=\text{lex}_{10,6}(123,1)=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87,6)=10-9=1
$$
Next, we compute $a_2$. Similar to before, we get $a_2=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87, 5)=10-c_5$. Using the formula, $c_5$ is the largest number so $\binom{c_5}5\le 87-\binom{9}6=3.$  Since $\binom{5}5\le 3$ and $\binom65> 3$, we conclude $c_5=5$, so $a_2=10-5=5$.

$a_3=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87, 4)=10-c_4$. Using the formula, $c_4$ is the largest number so $\binom{c_4}4\le 87-\binom{9}6-\binom 55=2.$  Since $\binom{4}4\le 2$ and $\binom54> 2$, we conclude $c_4=4$, so $a_3=10-4=6$.

$a_4=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87, 3)=10-c_3$. Using the formula, $c_3$ is the largest number so $\binom{c_3}3\le 87-\binom{9}6-\binom 55-\binom44=1.$  Since $\binom{3}3\le 1$ and $\binom43>1$, we conclude $c_3=3$, so $a_4=10-3=7$.

$a_5=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87, 2)=10-c_2$. Using the formula, $c_2$ is the largest number so $\binom{c_2}2\le 87-\binom{9}6-\binom 55-\binom44-\binom33=0.$  Since $\binom{1}2\le 0$ and $\binom22>0$, we conclude $c_2=1$, so $a_5=10-1=9$.

$a_6=10-\text{colex}_{10,6}(87, 1)=10-c_1$. Using the formula, $c_1$ is the largest number so $\binom{c_1}1\le 87-\binom{9}6-\binom 55-\binom44-\binom33-\binom 12=0.$  Since $\binom{0}1\le 0$ and $\binom11>0$, we conclude $c_1=0$, so $a_6=10-0=10$.


Finally, we have found that the $123^\text{rd}$ subset in the list is $\{a_1,\dots,a_6\}=\{1,5,6,7,9,10\}$.

TYVM too. Same question: would it be OK to ask whether you can demonstrate your algorithm using the numerical example n=5, k=3? Alternatively: could you calculate directly the 234th lexicographic list entry in the lottery game "6 out of 49"?

PS: For $(n,k)=(5,3)$ I get with your formula $
\text{lex}(1,1)=3,~
\text{lex}(1,2)=2,~
\text{lex}(1,3)=1,~
\text{lex}(2,1)=4.$ So the order Lex3, Lex2, Lex1. Cute!

I added a fully worked out example. The "6 out of 49" computation would require seven digit numbers, so I did a smaller example using only three digit numbers.
